# Django drop downs in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm currently providing choices in a dropdown in a model like this:

```
class FoodType(models.Model):
  type = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.type

class Food(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
  type = models.ForeignKey(FoodType)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

I did it like this rather than hardcoded choices because I want to provide an option to add/delete/change FoodTypes via the admin once the app is deployed. But then I realised once that if a FoodType is deleted that a Food is dependent on, the Food is also deleted, which I don't want. I want to be able to keep all Food records unless I explicitly want to delete one.

Is there a better way to do this that still allows the user to modify FoodTypes via the admin?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) parameter of the `ForeignKey` field to a value different than `CASCADE` (the default value).

Ex:

```
type = models.ForeignKey(FoodType, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: OK thanks that looks like what I'm after. I also thought I could do this by always keeping the FoodTypes, but setting an `is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)` so that I could customise the drop down to only populate the Food dropdown with FoodType records where `is_deleted=False`...not sure whether this would be good practice though, as the FoodTypes model could get confusing?

Comment: Indeed, "soft deletion" is the other solution, it is probably better practice but a bit harder to implement. There are [Django apps](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/deletion/) available that provide  it but I never used them myself, there also are a lot of articles on the subject.

Comment: I'm going to try and implement that solution but thanks for bringing `on_delete` to my attention, it'll definitely be useful for other applications!